# Lambda Expressions Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Nothing seems weird here:
2Classes. Interface.java and Lambdas.java

```
public class Lambdas {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Lambdas().start();
  }

  public void start(){
    Interface f = () -> Interface{System.out.println("test");}
  }
}

public interface Interface {
     void test();
}
```

I get error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Interface
  location: class lambdas.Lambdas .
I don't know why.

P.S. Just arrived home from Java Day 2014 , I use their examples - with netbeans

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong;

```
Interface f = () -> System.out.println("test");
```

Comment: You need braces around the statement.

Comment: @DavidConrad No you don't.

Comment: I could have sworn you needed a block-style lambda to call a method that returns void. Either they changed that in some build of Java 8, or my memory is faulty.

Comment: @DavidConrad No, you're right, it was necessary. I'm also surprised to find that it's changed.

Comment: @DavidConrad The JLS still quite clearly says "A lambda body is either a single expression or a block" (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27) So the compiler is being more permissive than the specification.

Comment: The spec will be amended, then.

Comment: A method invocation *is* “a single expression” even if the method returns `void`. At the time the source code is parsed according to the *grammar* of the Java language, things like return types do not matter, they are evaluated in a later step. [§15.27.3 says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3): “*If the function type's result is void, the lambda body is either a statement expression or a void-compatible block*.” And a method invocation is a “statement expression”. Reading formal specification correctly can be very tricky…

Comment: From what I learned on the talk , it was also a tweak made from the early/official release

Comment: @Holger is right. I actually knew this when I wrote example 4 on this page of the Lambda FAQ: http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-is-a-lambda-expression/, but forgot it at some point in the year since.

Comment: I found a [message from the lambda-dev](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-June/005032.html) mailing list that shows that my understanding was at least two years out of date, so thanks again assylias for correcting me! From June 6, 2012: `"the next EDR will include support for void methods as expression bodies"`